# Imported React component not being displayed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i've a react component that i import, but its not displayed on the page.

this is my app.js file. i imported the "functionalComponent" component but it is not getting displayed on the browser.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import functionalComponent from './functionalComponent';
import classComponent from './classComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     
      <functionalComponent/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my functionalComponent.js

```
import React from "react";

class functionalComponent extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return <p>This is a functional component.</p>
    }
}

export default functionalComponent;
```

and this is my App.test.js

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**React requires that the first letter of components be capitalized**
change your component name to FunctionalComponent and check if this fixes the issue.

```
import React from "react";
const FunctionalComponent = () => {   
    return <p>Functional component</p>   
}

export default FunctionalComponent;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React from "react";

const FunctionalComponent = () => {  
  // render() method does not exist we are no longer in a Class context
  return <p>This is a functional component.</p>   
}

export default FunctionalComponent ;
```

This is how a function component should look like, just like your `App` component, in your example you are using a class

Answer (score 0):

---

the component name should be FunctionalComponent, not functionalComponent. JavaScript is case-sensitive, so the incorrect casing prevents the component from being recognized.

```
import FunctionalComponent from './functionalComponent';

 function App() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
  <FunctionalComponent />
 </div>
  );
 }

export default App;
```

In functionalComponent.js:
import React from "react";

```
 class FunctionalComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
 return <p>This is a functional component.</p>;
  }
 }

export default FunctionalComponent;
```

Comment: however case sensitive is not the same thing as requiring the first letter to be capital.